# Is there any way to change the priority of the build queue on the fly in the java version of cruisecontrol?

Tags: cruisecontrol

I need a way to push a project to the top of the build queue. In front of all the other projects that are waiting.

This issue has happened for me a few times, and I haven't been able to find an answer at http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html

We are using cruisecontrol 2.8.3 to build approximately 20 projects.

Every so often the priority of one of the projects becomes important -->  We really need project X to be rebuilt even though it just built 5 minutes ago to include the latest bug fix.

Project X is now at the back of the build queue with 19 other projects in front of it, so it won't be finished building for another 2 hours.

Force build doesn't help me. The project is already on the build queue because a new change has been checked in.

Note that this project is not normally critical - so I don't want to always give it a higher priority.

Is there any thing that I'm missing? Is there any way to temporarily make my project more important?

Possible solutions I've thought of and rejected:
 - commenting out every other project in my config.xml and saving it

-- while that would probably work, it seems a little heavy handed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to change project priorities on the fly. You have to change your configuration file and then restart cruisecontrol.